# plotly python - fix colours for specific legend labels

Tags: python-3.x, charts, plotly, color-scheme

I am making a pie chart that looks like this.

I want to make multiple pie charts for different sets of data and keep the colours fixed to the legend names, but when the order changes, the colour scheme follows the order.

Is there a way to pass a dict into the chart to fix the colours to specific items?

[[image]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a dictionary with your colors, but you can specify the colors manually, set [`sort`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#pie-sort) to `False` and pass the values always in the same order, e.g.

```
import plotly

fig = {
    'data': [{'labels': ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
              'values': [19, 26, 55],
              'type': 'pie',
              'sort': False,
              'marker': {'colors': ['rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                                    'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                                    'rgb(0, 0, 255)']
                        }
            }]
     }

fig = {
    'data': [{'labels': ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
              'values': [100, 10, 25],
              'type': 'pie',
              'sort': False,
              'marker': {'colors': ['rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                                    'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                                    'rgb(0, 0, 255)']
                        }
            }]
     }
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: cool thanks for confirming. i think i'll try making a list of colours, reading the order of the generators, and re-ordering the colour list to match it